# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data is not defined in react component

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm passing a simple JSON object from the back-end to the front-end `{data: "test"}`. I got the following error on the react side `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data is not defined`. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious. Here is my Component:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = { data: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/data',    {
          method: 'GET',
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Accept': 'application/json' }})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    console.log(data)
    return (
      <div>
      <p> test </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you try to set the state to `data` which does not exist, although the json is passed in as argument `user`.

You might want to use `user`

```
.then(user => this.setState({ data: user }));
```

or rename the argument to `data`

```
.then(data => this.setState({ data }));
```